# Ethernet and wifi not working in newly installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on HP mini 1000

Tags: wireless, ethernet

I tried various options available on different webpages but nothing helped me.

like running command like 'lsusb'

Images of various command I executed are available at [Google image](https://goo.gl/photos/qLu2XddGxm7b7wdt6)

Comment: lsusb command lists your USB devices and can not help to solve any problem. How do you connect to internet?

Comment: Please see this to get your wireless working: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343096/wifi-drivers-wont-function/343145#343145

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried to connect via LAN cable. I also ran command like  **rfkill list all** provided link will show you output of various network related commands.